# Restoring deleted iteration path in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, restore

Is there any way to restore deleted iteration paths in azure devops?
I mistakenly deleted the iteration path for my entire organization on Friday.
All work items have been returned to the backlog and all previous sprint data erased.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure DevOps doesn't support restore deleted iterations. You need to add the iteration back manually, and edit the iteration path for the effected work items.

When you delete an area node or change the Location field for a node, the system automatically updates the existing work items with the node that you enter at the deletion prompt.

[image]